# LyX: Harvard Referencing using Natbib

Tags: bibliographies, lyx, natbib, harvard-style

I'm very new to TEX, i've been using LyX as a stepping stone. It's been going pretty well up until now.

I've successfully managed to create citations and link them to the References I have created in the bibliography.

However, I need to use the Harvard referencing system (author-date). I've switched to natbib style in document > settings > Bibliography and set it to author-year, however I'm unsure what format I should be entering for references so that it picks up the author & date.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Are you using a BibTeX bibliography (Insert --> List/TOC --> BibTeX bib) or are you writing it manually?

Answer (score 1):

If you're writing the bibliography yourself, then you need to add a *label* for each item. Right click the grey box in the reference list where the citation key is written - highlighted by the red ellipse in the screenshot below - and choose Settings (the only option).

[image]

In the *Label* field write `authorname(year)` *without a space before the parenthesis*, e.g. `Author(2012)`. Quoting the [`natbib` manual](http://texdoc.net/pkg/natbib):

oneself, such that it conforms to natbib.

> This syntax looks as follows:
>
> ```
> \bibitem[Jones et al.(1990)]{jon90}...
> ```
>
> or alternatively
>
> ```
> \bibitem[Jones et al.(1990)Jones, Baker, and Williams]{jon90}...
> ```
>
> The text in square brackets contains the pieces of citation texts, the
>   short author list, `Jones et al.`, the year `1990`, and the optional long
>   author list `Jones, Baker and Williams`. If the long list is missing,
>   the short list will be used instead. The parentheses around the year
>   are not part of the text, but merely delimit the year from the author
>   lists. Round parentheses must always be used, even if square brackets
>   are wanted for the citations. And there must be no space before or
>   after the year parentheses, else it will become part of the author
>   list.

Answer (score 0):

Assume you have a well-formed `bib` file.
It sounds as if you have already inserted a BibTex Generated Bibliography into your document (this is Torbjorn's question).

Right click on the that field in your document and select settings. From the `Style` dropdown box, select `unstr` (there may be others, but at least this one should get you started). OK and close.

Now `Insert Citation`. Add one of the selectable citations on the left to the empty right box. Now you can chose in the `Formatting` dropdown box your preferred presentation, and if you want add some text before or after the in your reference.

Comment: Wouldn't e.g. `plainnat` make more sense than `unsrt` for Harvard style?

Comment: @Torbjørn T., you probably know better than I do. Just suggested `unstr` because it allows to demonstrate the formatting the OP was looking for. So @Daniel, better go with `plainnat`

Comment: The point of `uns` o `rt` ed is to sort the references by the order of citation, but when using an author-year style it is more common to have them sorted alphabetically.

Answer (score 0):

To use Harvard style in Lyx, you will have to use label such as Author(2016) with no space before parenthesis.

And my setting looks like:
[image: Bibliography setting example]

The Harvard style is generated as expected:
[image]

Comment: This is already covered in the other answer...