# Bibliography style in Lyx?

Tags: bibliographies, bibtex, lyx

I am finalizing my dissertation an am trying to add the bibliograph using `Bibtex` and `JabRef` and would like to get some help. I have used the below link as a guidance of how to input references in `LyX`.

http://lars.mec.ua.pt/public/LAR%20Projects/Humanoid/2016_CesarSousa/Template_Lyx/Lyx-Install-References-Bibtex-1.pdf

Also, I have used the below question as guidance.[LyX: Harvard Referencing using Natbib](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/145009/lyx-harvard-referencing-using-natbib)

however I am still not getting the results I want.

The below screen shot are the fields I have used when inputting my bibtex bibliograph:
[image]

and this is the part were I have added the Nabib in the bibliography section

[image]

When adding the bibiliograph this is the output in pdf

[image]

However the output I am looking for is like this:

[image]

I am not sure which is the style used below, can someone help me please or guide me to use something to get to this result pls? Also, can I change the title from **Bibliography** to **References**?

Comment: My advice would be to use `biblatex+biber`. It is easier to customise if necessary, and it understands utf8.

Comment: @Bernard - I don't have `biber` and I am not sure what you meant by your comment.

Comment: You necessarily have `biber` with MiKTeX. By my comment, I meant that it's easy to make some modifications to the bib style if necessary (biblatex uses a latex syntax). uft8 means that when you have accented letters in your bibliography, you can type them as is (e.g. a simple `é` instead of `\´{e}`).

Comment: @Bernard - I have download the bibtex package in Miktex but I still did not manage to get the bibliography list as shown in the last figure above